# Issue copying an SVG image to a Word file

Tags: image, svg, ms-word, label

When I paste an SVG image to Word, the Y labels get disoriented.
Here is how it looks in browser:

[image: Text in the SVG seen in browser]

Here is how it looks pasted into a Word document:

[image: Same text in SVG seen in Microsoft Word, misaligned]

---

**Edit 1**: thank you for the answer.

Now the picture looks like this, still misaligned:

[image: Text in the SVG still misaligned]

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could try putting in the alt codes for superscript if using windows, otherwise I can't think of a simple answer. https://www.webnots.com/alt-code-shortcuts-for-superscript-and-subscript/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having your issue is in part because there are two text elements,
one for `10` and one for `²` etc..

If you have an understanding of how to navigate the code you would:

> find each instance of `10`  and put (copy & paste):
> `10⁴`, `10²`, `10⁰`, `10⁻²`
> And while your at each `10` find the
> `4`, `2`, `0`, `-2`

and just leave an empty element there.

example of what you have:

```html
<text>10</text>
<text>2</text>
```

example of what you want:

```html
<text>10²</text>
<text></text>
```

note the second element might be

```html
<tspan></tspan>
```

---

If this doesn't work,
You could try putting in the [alt codes for superscript if using windows](https://www.webnots.com/alt-code-shortcuts-for-superscript-and-subscript).

Otherwise you could try:

- write superscript character in word
- copy that superscript character into the svg code
- save svg
- import the svg back into word
- if works, do the same for the rest of the characters